# Shrink overflowing content to fit container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible in CSS (if not, javascript?) to shrink content that overflows its container, rather than hide it?

I have a box with some text etc, which shrinks in width as the viewport gets smaller, and the height is restricted too. All the content needs to remain visible, but within the bounds. Scroll is not an option.

```css
body {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>example title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati fugiat dolore amet odit quaerat iusto sapiente ea quod atque necessitatibus id eius accusantium itaque voluptatibus laborum, doloremque, recusandae, nobis consequatur.</p>
  <button>a button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use a site like jsfiddle.net to practice with messing around in code without having to hit save and refresh a site if you're running a local development server. Hope this can help you out in a pinch to learn small HTML stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the question is a little unclear, but you could look into using [`viewport width`](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) font-size. It will resize based on the screen size:

```css
body {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}
button {
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>example title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati fugiat dolore amet odit quaerat iusto sapiente ea quod atque necessitatibus id eius accusantium itaque voluptatibus laborum, doloremque, recusandae, nobis consequatur.</p>
  <button>a button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could work. Content will still be hidden if there's some more of it though. A better solution might also only take effect if the content is actually overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to adjust the `font-size` of a `span` inside a `div`:

```
function adjustHeights(elem) {
  var fontstep = 2;
  if ($(elem).height() > $(elem).parent().height() || $(elem).width() > $(elem).parent().width()) {
    $(elem).css('font-size', (($(elem).css('font-size').substr(0, 2) - fontstep)) + 'px').css('line-height', (($(elem).css('font-size').substr(0, 2))) + 'px');
    adjustHeights(elem);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="text">
sldfjslfjladf
sf
as
f
wer
qwreqwrewasdf
sd
f
s
fs
df
s
ffadsssssssssssssssssssssssssssss


asdf<br/>
sdf
s

dsfsfaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</span>
</div>
<script>
  function adjustHeights(elem) {
    var fontstep = 2;
    if ($(elem).height() > $(elem).parent().height() || $(elem).width() > $(elem).parent().width()) {
      $(elem).css('font-size', (($(elem).css('font-size').substr(0, 2) - fontstep)) + 'px').css('line-height', (($(elem).css('font-size').substr(0, 2))) + 'px');
      adjustHeights(elem);
    }
  }
  var div = document.getElementById("text");
  adjustHeights(div);
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8B9j/1390/

Answer (score -1):

SVG with text element.

Make an svg with expandable text.

It will eventually be hard to read.

```
<div style="width: 60px;">  
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -200 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text font-size="300" fill="black">Text</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Non styled example
https://jsfiddle.net/k8L4xLLa/32/

Cool styled example
https://jsfiddle.net/k8L4xLLa/14/

You can use media queries to change the font size when needed.

Honestly though, consider flexbox. Its a much cleaner solution that does not make the text scalable. Then you can wrap your elements when theyre too small. :)